# Title of NSButton disappears on setAttributedTitle:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring, appkit

After executing this code button's title disappears sometimes, but not always. What can be a solution for this?

```
NSColor *color = [NSColor whiteColor];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
NSString *content = @"Hello world!";
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:content attributes:@{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
    NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: @3,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
}];
[button setAttributedTitle:title];
```

Comment: Where and when are you calling this code? Is it possibly on a background thread?

Comment: @Koen this code executes on main thread in `awakeFromNib`

Comment: Try moving it to `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

NSButton has an 'On' state and an 'Off' state, .attributedTitle refers to the title in the 'Off' state, and .attributedAlternateTitle is the title in the 'On' state, so you have to set both.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton

Comment: He's using AppKit, not UIKit.